# are these (integral) properties true?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

is it true that:
$$1-\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) =\int_{1}^n f(k)\ dk\\ 2-\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)\ dx=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)\ dx$$
is true to replace summation by integration?

Comment: first one seemed unreasonable to me when I first encountered it, but how could 2 be false too?for instance:$$\\ \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac {-1}{x^2}\ dx=  \frac 1{\infty}-\frac 12=0-\frac 12=-\frac 12=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac 1n-\frac 12)$$

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to plug in some simple functions to test this? Say $f(k)=k$?

Answer (score 0):

First one is false.  I suppose your  variable of integration $k$ on RHS is not the same as the integer variable on LHS.

You can change the values of $f$ at the integers any way you like without changing the integral so the equality cannot hold.
The second in the definitioin  of the improper integral $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

No.  In the first, take $n=1$ to see that $1 - f(1) = 0$ can only possibly be true for the very special collection of $f$s that have $f(1) = 1$.  The second cannot be true in general because the *definition* of $\int_a^\infty f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^n f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$, so the equality you write can only be true if the value of the right-hand side (which is also the value of the integral on the left-hand side) is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Both are not correct. For the first let $f(x)=x$.Then $1-\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) =1 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\int_{1}^n f(k)\ dk= \frac{1}{2}n^2- \frac{1}{2}.$

If $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)\ dx$ exists, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)\ dx= \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)\ dx.$